# C++ method declaration including a macro

Tags: c++, class, macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I'm using QuickFAST library and while checking it I found this class declaration which I don't seem to really get ! I mean what does a macro name before the class name !

```
class QuickFAST_Export Message : public FieldSet
```

also I found this declaration

```
friend void QuickFAST_Export intrusive_ptr_add_ref(const Field * ptr);
```

and again I don't get the use of this declaration !

for more info here's the QuickFAST_Export.hpp

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# pragma once
#endif
#ifndef QUICKFAST_EXPORT_H
#define QUICKFAST_EXPORT_H

// Compile time controls for library generation.  Define with /D or #define
// To produce or use a static library: #define QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL=0
//   Default is to produce/use a DLL
// While building the QUICKFAST_ library: #define QUICKFAST_BUILD_DLL
//   Default is to export symbols from a pre-built QUICKFAST DLL
//
// Within QUICKFAST use the QuickFAST_Export macro where a __declspec is needed.

#if defined (_WIN32)

#  if !defined (QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL)
#    define QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL 1
#  endif /* ! QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL */

#  if defined (QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL) && (QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL == 1)
#    if defined (QUICKFAST_BUILD_DLL)
#      define QuickFAST_Export __declspec(dllexport)
#    else /* QUICKFAST_BUILD_DLL */
#      define QuickFAST_Export __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif /* QUICKFAST_BUILD_DLL */
#  else /* QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL == 1 */
#    define QuickFAST_Export
#  endif /* QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL == 1 */

#  else /* !_WIN32 */
```

Comment: You should search for e.g. `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` to learn what they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the class is either exported or imported, depending on which module is built.

If `QUICKFAST_HAS_DLL` is defined and equal to 1, it means that the module is built as a DLL. To use functionalities from the outside, classes and methods have to be exported.

Inside the module, `QUICKFAST_BUILD_DLL` is defined. So when you build the module, `QuickFAST_Export` expands to `__declspec(dllexport)`. Your class definition becomes:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Message : public FieldSet
```

When you include the header from a different module, `QUICKFAST_BUILD_DLL` is not defined, so the macro expands to `__declspec(dllimport)`, and your class definition to:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) Message : public FieldSet
```

Comment: ok I got it now , but putting the __declspec(dllimport) before className what is supposed to do to the body of my class, I mean I still don't get this declaration , I know that for déclaring a class all we need to do is "class className : public ClassBase" , so what is this new declaration?

Comment: @Glolita have you tried googling the syntax? It tells the linker that class is to be exported.

Comment: @Glolita I have exactly the same question. People don't seem to answer my (our) question satisfactorily. I guess my real question is, what actual thing is `__declspec(dllimport)` exactly, and how is it legal syntax in C++ to put it in the middle of a class declaration? So I'm afraid @LuchianGrigore's comment doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

The macro expands to either `__declspec(dllimport)` or  `__declspec(dllexport)`, depending if the class is exported from the DLL or imported on the other side.