# What does this extra keyword mean in this c++ class declaration?

Tags: c++

I'm looking at some C++ code which declares a class like this:

```
class LIBSBML_EXTERN LayoutModelPlugin : public SBasePlugin
```

What is the LIBSBML_EXTERN keyword for?

Comment: It's a macro.  You'll need to search your code base for its definition.

Comment: It's not a keyword; keywords are defined by the language specification. It's probably a macro that's defined by some library that this code is using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ method declaration including a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210449/c-method-declaration-including-a-macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a macro. I'm not sure exactly what libraries you're using, but likely it's the macro with the definition you can see here: https://github.com/copasi/copasi-dependencies/blob/master/src/libSBML/src/sbml/common/extern.h

```cpp
#if ( ! defined LIBSBML_STATIC )
/**
 * The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which
 * make exporting from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are
 * compiled with the LIBSBML_EXPORTS symbol defined on the command line.
 * This symbol should not be defined on any project that uses this
 * DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see
 * LIBSBML_EXTERN functions as being imported from a DLL, wheras this DLL
 * sees symbols defined with this macro as being exported.
 *
 * (From Andrew Finney's sbwdefs.h, with "SBW" replaced by "LIBSBML" :)
 */
#if defined(LIBSBML_EXPORTS)
#  define LIBSBML_EXTERN __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define LIBSBML_EXTERN __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#else
#  define LIBSBML_EXTERN
#endif  /* LIBSBML_STATIC */
```

It is used to interface the class definition with DLLs, if required.

Comment: Got it, this makes sense - thought there was another mistical part of C++ class declarations for a moment there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a macro, something that you would define like this:

```
#define LIBSBML_EXTERN whatever
```

where `whatever` is what the compiler puts in place of `LIBSBML_EXTERN` before compiling.